# How can I make my linearlayout height wrap_content instead of match_parent?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make images in this layout (with id itemslayout) wrap the image rather than match the parent height. The imageviews dont seem to listen to my XML code! What is the solution. Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullupTitleBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <xx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.android.ui.views.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/someTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/lolperks"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/upanddownButton"
            style="@style/OrangeSmallButton"
            android:layout_width="37dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/double_arrows"
            android:contentDescription="UpButton"
            android:onClick="downButtonClicked"
            android:scaleY="-1"
            android:text=" " />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="pick a card any card "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/itemslayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.333" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/card" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.333" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/card" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.333"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/card" />

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is a screenshot of what is happening. I need it to be wrapping the image not matching the parent. 
[image: wrap_content]

What i want:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have a frame layout for each ImageView?

Comment: Because I will add other content in here like buttons etc later on :).

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure you can't use wrap_content or match_parent if your using layout weight for childs. You are basically saying that it should fit content  size(childs size), but your childs refers to the size of the parent(weight). That's strange.

Comment: so... what is the solution? I still need to have 3 per row that scales to 100% of the screen width.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding your question. In your title, you are saying that you want **linearlayout height match_parent instead of wrap_content** but before the screenshot you say you want **I need it to be wrapping the image not matching the parent**.

Comment: my bad title updated!

Comment: Can you draw what you want?

Comment: Ok updated with drawing of what I want.

Comment: What's your itemsLayout orientation? And, is your current layout appearing like the 'do not want image'?

Comment: yes and orientation="horizontal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it might sound confusing, but try putting one more layout inside of the outermost layout and set the height to wrap_content. With layouts, it causes everything inside of it to wrap content rather than causing the actual layout to do it. You need this buffer layout though so that the outermost layout will still fill the whole screen.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/pullupTitleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <xx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.android.ui.views.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/someTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lolperks"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upanddownButton"
        style="@style/OrangeSmallButton"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/double_arrows"
        android:contentDescription="UpButton"
        android:onClick="downButtonClicked"
        android:scaleY="-1"
        android:text=" " />
</FrameLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="pick a card any card "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/itemslayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.333" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/card" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.333" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/card" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.333"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/card" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. My outer layout is already wrapping content?

Comment: Your outermost layout is your linear layout. it is matching parent. It may be causing your frame layout to match it. I had trouble with this in a previous project. Try it out and see if it works. I added the linear layout to my original answer look at it to see what I mean.

Comment: My outermost layout is actually a relative layout. It has to be because of the Custom classes I include in the real project.

Comment: Try adding the linear layout just inside of the other one where I added it. If that doesn't work, I would try using a linear layout instead of relative and nesting the relative somewhere inside for your custom classes. Relative layouts break everything.

Comment: it did not make a difference for me.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. Its always worth a try because it only takes a minute or so to throw in an extra layout or two.

Comment: this methodology worked for me in the end thanks :).